# Contains Duplicate II Exceeded time solution

Tags: python

I've written a Python solution for the Contains Duplicate II leetcode problem, but when I test it I get a "time limit exceeded" message. However, I'm confused because I thought my solution is O(n) runtime. Could someone please explain?

```
    def containsNearbyDuplicate(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: bool
        """

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            lookingfor = nums[i]

            rest = nums[i+1: ]
            if lookingfor in rest:
                secondindex = rest.index(lookingfor)+i+1
                if abs(i - secondindex) <= k:
                    return True

        return False
```

Comment: index is O(n) on list so the total complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: Could you explain why you think your runtime is linear?

Comment: Ah I see, I had thought that since accessing elements in a list/array is O(1), the index() method is also constant time -- this was mistaken. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

In general, using `in` to search for an element in a list takes linear time.

Applying this to your code, we can observe that the search in `rest` takes `O(len(nums))` times, which you repeat `O(len(nums))` times. That leads to a quadratic runtime, causing your submission to TLE.

To get a linear runtime, use a dictionary:

```py
class Solution:
    def containsNearbyDuplicate(self, nums, k):
        seen = {}
        for index, element in enumerate(nums):
            if element in seen and index - seen[element] <= k:
                return True
            seen[element] = index
        return False
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification! it makes sense now -- I had thought the index() method is constant time